# Specialized Cell.init(coder:) Crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im receiving a crash `<compiler-generated> line 0 specialized MessagesCell.init(coder:)` over Firebase, this crash is being received only on iOS 9.2.x or 9, i have tried to trace it and understand what is exactly happening but on the simulator its not happening at all.

Here is the way i register the cells for tableView:

```
self.messagesTable.register(MessagesCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")
self.messagesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MessagesCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")
```

Here is my cell class:

```
import UIKit

class MessagesCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet  var myContentView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Here is the crash log and any help will be appreciated:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x183333be8 szone_free + 2944
1  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x183333738 szone_free + 1744
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1836459a4 CFRelease + 1088
3  CoreUI                         0x18827e40c -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:usingKeySignature:] + 1600
4  CoreUI                         0x1882a035c -[CUICatalog _storageRefForRendition:representsODRContent:] + 104
5  CoreUI                         0x1882a0124 -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 188
6  UIKit                          0x188cb5994 __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424
7  UIKit                          0x188cb5734 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 212
8  UIKit                          0x188472320 -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:] + 140
9  UIKit                          0x1889235e0 -[UIImageNibPlaceholder initWithCoder:] + 488
10 UIKit                          0x1946dacfc -[UIImageNibPlaceholderAccessibility initWithCoder:] + 52
11 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
12 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
13 UIKit                          0x1888058f4 -[UIImageView initWithCoder:] + 132
14 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
15 UIKit                          0x188a427f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
16 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
17 UIKit                          0x18875c5d0 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 608
18 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
19 UIKit                          0x188a427f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
20 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
21 UIKit                          0x18875c5d0 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 608
22 UIKit                          0x188a93678 -[UITableViewCellContentView initWithCoder:] + 48
23 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
24 UIKit                          0x188a427f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
25 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
26 UIKit                          0x18875c5d0 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 608
27 UIKit                          0x1888f4630 -[UITableViewCell initWithCoder:] + 100
28 APP_NAME                       0x100085464 specialized MessagesCell.init(coder:) (<compiler-generated>)
29 APP_NAME                       0x100084fb0 @objc MessagesCell.init(coder:) (<compiler-generated>)
30 UIKit                          0x1889224b8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 248
31 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
32 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
33 UIKit                          0x188922128 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 136
34 UIKit                          0x188a4267c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 672
35 UIKit                          0x188a427f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1048
36 UIKit                          0x188a423c4 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 336
37 UIKit                          0x188921490 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1220
38 UIKit                          0x1885a3c18 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 584
39 UIKit                          0x1946a5954 -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:] + 140
40 UIKit                          0x1885dfbd4 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 88
41 UIKit                          0x1946a5a18 -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 180
42 APP_NAME                       0x1000c07bc MessagesDetail.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (MessagesDetail.swift:320)
43 APP_NAME                       0x1000c1c84 @objc MessagesDetail.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (<compiler-generated>)
44 UIKit                          0x1887a931c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 692
45 UIKit                          0x1887a9484 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 80
46 UIKit                          0x1887987e8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2360
47 UIKit                          0x1887adfb0 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 104
48 UIKit                          0x18854308c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
49 UIKit                          0x188453778 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
50 QuartzCore                     0x185e62b2c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
51 QuartzCore                     0x185e5d738 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
52 QuartzCore                     0x185e5d5f8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
53 QuartzCore                     0x185e5cc94 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
54 QuartzCore                     0x185e5c9dc CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
55 QuartzCore                     0x185e560cc CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
56 CoreFoundation                 0x18371c588 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
57 CoreFoundation                 0x18371a32c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
58 CoreFoundation                 0x18371a75c __CFRunLoopRun + 928
59 CoreFoundation                 0x183649680 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
60 GraphicsServices               0x184b58088 GSEventRunModal + 180
61 UIKit                          0x1884c0d90 UIApplicationMain + 204
62 APP_NAME                       0x100075f08 main (AppDelegate.swift:20)
63 ???                            0x1831ea8b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Did. you find a resolution for this ..? @Aaoli

Comment: @RaghavChopra Using the below answer did help to fix this crash, you don’t need to add init coder. Just the below code.

Comment: @Aaoli In my case, it is a view controller, can you please lok into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031678/crash-reported-generated-by-compiler-in-swift-5-xcode-13

Answer (score 0):

You only need to register the cell by either of the two ways. So, you can keep the second option

```
self.messagesTable.register(UINib(nibName: "MessagesCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")
```

Comment your first line, and it will start working.

```
//self.messagesTable.register(MessagesCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")
```

For registering with `self.messagesTable.register(MessagesCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessagesCell")` you will also need to add `init(coder:)`

Try and share your results.

Comment: Hmm, but adding an empty init coder will prevent the crash ?

Comment: Why it crash only on iOS 9 ?

Comment: hmm... what results are you getting after commenting that line? is that still crashing? if so, then probably the reason might be somewhere else, because from the logs, it can be seen from here, that: 
28 APP_NAME                       0x100085464 specialized MessagesCell.init(coder:) (<compiler-generated>)
29 APP_NAME                       0x100084fb0 @objc MessagesCell.init(coder:) (<compiler-generated>)

Compiler is generating it, while building the app.

Comment: @BhavinKansagara How do I need to. add init(coder:)

to viewcontroller class