# Crash reported generated by Compiler in Swift 5 xcode 11

Tags: swift3, compiler-errors

My app has been rejected from Apple quite a long time now.
They say that I get crash on dashboard but although it works fine on simulator and device

I implemented 2 approaches to get the crash report

1. Firebase Analytics
2. Symbolised the crash reported shared by Apple.

   .init(coder:)

It says error generated by compiler

```
8   SSBS                            0x10521c174 DashboardViewController.init(coder:) + 5308788 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   SSBS                            0x10521c238 @objc DashboardViewController.init(coder:) + 5308984 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

In this case, what do I need to implement in my ViewController Class file
So the crash report generated fr
om that is :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

*Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1adc3b794 0x1adb11000 + 1222548
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ad95dbcc 0x1ad958000 + 23500
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1adb31b98 0x1adb11000 + 134040
3   UIKitCore                       0x1b1652c74 0x1b12b4000 + 3796084
4   UIFoundation                    0x1b123fe94 0x1b11d5000 + 437908
5   UIFoundation                    0x1b12400b4 0x1b11d5000 + 438452
6   UIFoundation                    0x1b11dccac 0x1b11d5000 + 31916
7   UIKitCore                       0x1b1699dd0 0x1b12b4000 + 4087248
8   SSBS                            0x10521c174 DashboardViewController.init(coder:) + 5308788 (<compiler-generated>:0)
9   SSBS                            0x10521c238 @objc DashboardViewController.init(coder:) + 5308984 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1b1973c40 0x1b12b4000 + 7076928
11  UIFoundation                    0x1b123fe94 0x1b11d5000 + 437908
12  UIFoundation                    0x1b11dccac 0x1b11d5000 + 31916
13  UIKitCore                       0x1b1977bbc 0x1b12b4000 + 7093180
14  UIFoundation                    0x1b123fe94 0x1b11d5000 + 437908
15  UIFoundation                    0x1b12400b4 0x1b11d5000 + 438452
16  UIFoundation                    0x1b11dccac 0x1b11d5000 + 31916
17  UIKitCore                       0x1b1972cd8 0x1b12b4000 + 7072984
18  UIKitCore                       0x1b1975858 0x1b12b4000 + 7084120
19  UIKitCore                       0x1b1e4784c 0x1b12b4000 + 12138572
20  SSBS                            0x1052b55a8 closure #1 in LoginViewController.RegisterUserOnServer() + 5936552 (LoginViewController.swift:707)
21  Alamofire                       0x105e47454 0x105d54000 + 996436
22  Alamofire                       0x105d7ac94 0x105d54000 + 158868
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad9009a8 0x1ad8a6000 + 371112
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad901524 0x1ad8a6000 + 374052
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ad8b35b4 0x1ad8a6000 + 54708
26  CoreFoundation                  0x1adbb97fc 0x1adb11000 + 690172
27  CoreFoundation                  0x1adbb46d0 0x1adb11000 + 669392
28  CoreFoundation                  0x1adbb3ce8 0x1adb11000 + 666856
29  GraphicsServices                0x1b7cfe38c 0x1b7cfb000 + 13196
30  UIKitCore                       0x1b1ce2444 0x1b12b4000 + 10675268
31  SSBS                            0x1051ba4b4 main + 4908212 (AppDelegate.swift:21)
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x1ada3b8f0 0x1ada3a000 + 6384
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ada30d88 0x1ada0b000 + 155016
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ad9491e8 0x1ad947000 + 8680
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ad89c9b0 0x1ad82a000 + 469424
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ad89c940 0x1ad82a000 + 469312
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ada04cc0 0x1ad9f2000 + 76992
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ad9f6e10 0x1ad9f2000 + 19984
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ad95de80 0x1ad958000 + 24192
7   SSBS                            0x0000000105501948 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 8345928 (FIRCLSException.mm:338)
8   SSBS                            0x00000001054abc90 CLSTerminateHandler+ 7994512 () + 348
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ada0414c 0x1ad9f2000 + 74060
10  libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ada040e4 0x1ad9f2000 + 73956
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ad901538 0x1ad8a6000 + 374072
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001ad8b35b4 0x1ad8a6000 + 54708
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001adbb97fc 0x1adb11000 + 690172
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001adbb46d0 0x1adb11000 + 669392
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001adbb3ce8 0x1adb11000 + 666856
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001b7cfe38c 0x1b7cfb000 + 13196
17  UIKitCore                       0x00000001b1ce2444 0x1b12b4000 + 10675268
18  SSBS                            0x00000001051ba4b4 main + 4908212 (AppDelegate.swift:21)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ada3b8f0 0x1ada3a000 + 6384*
```

code of DashboardViewController:

```
class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //navigationHeaderItem()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            if(self.isNewDashboard == nil || self.isNewDashboard == true){
                self.newDashboardView.isHidden = false
            }else{
                self.newDashboardView.isHidden = true
            }

            let menuMangerObj = MenuDrawerManager()
            let resultItem=menuMangerObj.getByItemDrawerItem("My Meetings") as NSArray
            if(resultItem.count>0){
                self.newDashboardView.isHidden = false
            }else{
                self.newDashboardView.isHidden = true
            }
            self.loginUserName.text=userdDefaultData.string(forKey: "loginUserName")
    }
}
```

I initiate a view controller like:

```
                let vcObj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardController") as! DashboardViewController
                vcObj.isNewDashboard = true
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vcObj, animated: true)
```

Am I am missing anything here?

Comment: How do u initiate the view controller ?

Comment: @AaoIi I use storyboard to initiate the view controller, I have updated my question

Comment: You need to finish symbolicating the crash report. This question is pointless if you can’t say what the crash is. I don’t think it has anything to do with the code in DashboardViewController. Of the code you’ve shown, the likeliest issue is the phrase `as! DashboardViewController`.

Comment: @matt I have already symbolicated my crash report, I don't understand is there nay disconnect understanding my question, I have already highlighted  where is the crash but  not able to know where is this crash coming from

Comment: No you have not symbolicated it.

Comment: @matt but I have symbolized with the terminal window with the below command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash  /Users/mac/Desktop/symbolicatecrash/crash2.crash >  /Users/mac/Desktop/symbolicatecrash/crash2_symbolicated.crash

Comment: @matt I can see the class which is involved in my crash report , What do you mean by symbolicated

Comment: Look at the crash log. Lines 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 are nonsense. You need to symbolicate so we can read them and see what the crash is. Also the exception message itself is missing.

Comment: @matt what about line no 8 an 9  what is with that.?

Comment: @matt what can be the best way to achieve to symbolicate the crash report any suggestions

Comment: @matt I used Xcode to symbolicate my report and the same report I got. I don't know what I am missing

Comment: @matt I have managed to rectify my issue because of UISearchDisplayController was not supported to in my UIViewController shared in the crash report, anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: UISearchDisplayController has been deprecated for many years. And you didn’t mention it anywhere in your question or the crash report.